# Selectively allow cookies in firefox

Tags: firefox, cookies

In Chromium I can disable cookies and then in the address bar, enable them for individual sites, as seen below.

[image: whitelist cookies in address bar]

Is there a way to get the same functionality in firefox? I know I can go into "Preferences" to whitelist a site, but having this functionality in the address bar is much more convenient than going all the way into the preferences.

I'm totally open to add-ons as well, I just haven't found any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to do this in Firefox. It's a bit more complex than Chromium, but it does the trick.

1. First, open Firefox Preferences (about:preferences).
2. Click Privacy, and then click Firefox Will: Remember History. In the dropdown menu, click Use Custom Settings for History
3. Uncheck the box marked Accept Cookies from Sites, then click Exceptions.
4. In the popup box, enter the URLs of the sites you wish to keep cookies from.
   The screenshots had to be removed due to too many links.

**EDIT** After some searching I have also found [Cookie Controler](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/cookie-controller/). If you add the "Cookie Permissions" button to your toolbar, it allows you an easy way to disable/enable cookies for sites. It *is* Legacy so won't last forever but hopefully the dev will update it.  *(Editor's note: Not available as of 2023.)*

Comment: The problem with this solution is that I have to do go to preferences to do this. If I register myself on a new website for instance, I usually have to enable cookies to for that site. Chromium is much more convenient in this sense because I can whitelist the site simply by clicking on the icon in the address bar, as is visible in my screenshot. In firefox I have to go all the way to the preferences page.

Comment: I did say it would be a bit more complex...

Comment: Thanks for the hint in your "Edit". While your suggestion works, I didn't end up using it because I found one I like better [instead](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cookie-whitelist-with-buttons/). It gives me the ability to disable/reenable cookies globally, but also offers a button to whitelist individual sites. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! That's the first "marked as correct I ever got on Stack Exchange!!!

Comment: As of 2023, the browser extension mentioned in this answer, and the one mentioned in the comment, are no longer available.